# C - Node in a linked list somehow modified, results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am learning about linked lists and pointers in C, and am trying to implement a simple program that lets a user insert, delete, or search for an integer in a (singly) linked list of integers. When I try to insert a number, I'm fairly certain my insert function is working properly.

However, I have a function that prints the list to the terminal, and during the execution of that function, the node that was inserted is somehow modified so that its integer ('n') becomes some garbage value, and its 'next' pointer is changed so that it points to itself! The print function then keeps printing this node's 'n' value because its 'next' pointer is always pointing to itself, but the 'n' value keeps changing and on the third iteration I get a segfault (see gdb session at bottom).

Here is my definition of a node:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    // declare a linked list
    node* first = NULL;

    int command;
    int n;

    while (true)
    {
        printf("MENU\n\n");

        printf("1 - delete\n");
        printf("2 - insert\n");
        printf("3 - search\n");
        printf("0 - quit\n\n");

        printf("Enter a command: ");
        scanf("%i", &command);

        switch(command)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Hope u had fun (:\n");
                return 0;
            case 1:
                printf("Number to delete: ");
                scanf("%i", &n);
                deleteNode(n, &first);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Number to insert: ");
                scanf("%i", &n);
                insertNode(n, &first);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Number to search for: ");
                scanf("%i", &n);
                if (searchList(n, first))
                {
                    printf("Found %i in list!\n", n);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Did not find %i in list :(\n", n);
                }
        }

        printList(first);
    }
}
```

Here is my insertNode() function:

```
void insertNode(int n, node** first)
{
    // declare our new node
    node myNode;
    myNode.n = n;
    myNode.next = NULL;

    // initialize curNode to a pointer to the first node in the list
    node* curNode = *first;

    // initialize a pointer that will point to the previous node in the list if we need it
    node* prevNode = NULL;

    while (curNode != NULL)
    {
        if (n <= curNode->n)
        {
            // if prevNode is null, there's one element in the list
            // and we're inserting before it (i.e. at first position)
            if (prevNode == NULL)
            {
                *first      = &myNode;
                myNode.next = curNode;
                return;
            }
            // else, we're inserting between prevNode and curNode
            else
            {
                prevNode->next = &myNode;
                myNode.next    = curNode;
                return;
            }
        }
        // if n > curNode->n, move on to next node
        else
        {
            curNode  = curNode->next;
            prevNode = curNode;
        }
    }

    // curNode is null down here, so we're either at the end of the list, or the list is empty
    if (prevNode == NULL)
    {
        // empty list, only have to update first
        *first = &myNode;
    }
    else
    {
        // end of the list, only have to update previous node
        prevNode->next = &myNode;
    }
}
```

Here is my printList() function:

```
void printList(node* ptr)
{
    printf("\nLIST IS NOW: ");

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%i ", ptr->n);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Here is a gdb session that illustrates the bug:

```
35              printf("Enter a command: ");
(gdb)
Enter a command: 36             scanf("%i", &command);
(gdb)
2
38              switch(command)
(gdb) n
49                      printf("Number to insert: ");
(gdb)
Number to insert: 50                    scanf("%i", &n);
(gdb)
1
51                      insertNode(n, &first);
(gdb) s
insertNode (n=1, first=0x22fe48) at linked_list.c:78
78          myNode.n = n;
(gdb) n
79          myNode.next = NULL;
(gdb)
82          node* curNode = *first;
(gdb) p &myNode
$1 = (node *) 0x22fdf0
(gdb) n
85          node* prevNode = NULL;
(gdb)
87          while (curNode != NULL)
(gdb) p *first
$2 = (node *) 0x0
(gdb) p curNode
$3 = (node *) 0x0
(gdb) n
116         if (prevNode == NULL)
(gdb)
119             *first = &myNode;
(gdb)
126     }
(gdb) p *first
$4 = (node *) 0x22fdf0
(gdb) n
main () at linked_list.c:52
52                      break;
(gdb)
66              printList(first);
(gdb) p first
$5 = (node *) 0x22fdf0
(gdb) p *first
$6 = {n = 1, next = 0x0}
(gdb) s
printList (ptr=0x22fdf0) at linked_list.c:200
200         printf("\nLIST IS NOW: ");
(gdb) p ptr
$7 = (node *) 0x22fdf0
(gdb) p *ptr
$8 = {n = 1, next = 0x0}
(gdb) n

LIST IS NOW: 202            while (ptr != NULL)
(gdb) p ptr
$9 = (node *) 0x22fdf0
(gdb) p *ptr
$10 = {n = 4210908, next = 0x22fdf0}
(gdb) n
204             printf("%i ", ptr->n);
(gdb)
4210908 205             ptr = ptr->next;
(gdb)
202         while (ptr != NULL)
(gdb)
204             printf("%i ", ptr->n);
(gdb)
1397312522 205          ptr = ptr->next;
(gdb)
202         while (ptr != NULL)
(gdb)
204             printf("%i ", ptr->n);
(gdb)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401864 in printList (ptr=0x2500203a574f4e20) at linked_list.c:204
204             printf("%i ", ptr->n);
```

As you can see above, the node literally changes in the middle of the printList() function. How/why is this happening???

Comment: `node myNode;` lives in automatic storage.

Comment: I tried running the program and it went into an infinite loop!

Comment: oohh wow that makes sense. so i'm assuming I would have to do a malloc() from within the insert function to allocate the memory for the new node, and that way it won't be overwritten?

Comment: @dcsmith926 Where are hurry? At first see my answer.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking on every line you wrote, I noticed, that you did not dynamically allocate memory for your list.
In the insertNode function you define an element, which will reside on the stack:

```
node myNode;
```

If the function is left, the memory is "gone". This means you are not allowed to access it. But you pass it back to the main context with

```
*first      = &myNode;
```

The function must allocate memory by itself (for example with malloc).
To make the function simpler, do not pass a double pointer to this function.

On the opposite, the delteNode function must give back the memory to the operation system (for example with free). Also here: do not pass an address of a pointer, but just the position (the pointer) where the element should be deleted.

Comment: He must pass a pointer to the head pointer to his insert, otherwise he's unable to change the head pointer in the main function. Though a more functional style using the return value would IMHO be better.

Answer (score 0):

node myNode; in insertnode may point to the same memory over and over try using malloc instead so that each instance of the inserted node is guaranteed to be a unique memory position.

Answer (score 0):

Function `insertNode` is wrong at least because it uses a pointer to local variable `myNode` to include it in the list though this local variable will be destroyed after exiting the function and the pointer will be invalid.

That is the function has undefined behaviour.

Moreover it is too complicated.

It can be written the following way. Take into account that the first parameter should be the "list" and the added number should be the second parameter. Otherwise it is a bad style of programming.

```
void insertNode( node** first, int n )
{
    node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    tmp->n = n;

    if ( *first == NULL || n < ( *first )-> n )
    {
        tmp->next = *first;
        *first = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *current = *first;
        while ( current->next != NULL && !( n < current->n ) ) current = current->next;

        tmp->next = current->next;
        current->next = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your insertNode() function you are using address of a local variable.

// declare our new node

**node myNode;**

.
.

if (prevNode == NULL)

{

```
    // empty list, only have to update first
    first = &myNode;  // Trying to assign address of a local variable
```

}

Memory for "myNode" gets deallocated once the function gets over.Never do this.

Instead, Try dynamic memory allocation of memory for myNode.

node * myNode =NULL;

myNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

myNode->n = n;

myNode->next = NULL;

while assigning myNode,

*first = myNode;

Memory for the local variables are allocated on stack and it's lifetime is only till the function executes.

When you try to fetch the value stored there, there is good chance that you will get a segmentation fault.